# How to calculate percentage of row value in sum of total values in that column in python?

Tags: python

I have data frame containing red and blue balloons and I want to see what is the percentage of either balloons using Python:

Current:
Balloons Count
Red      10
Blue     90

Wanted:
Balloons Count Percentage
Red      10    10%
Blue     90    90%

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I tried data['Percentage'] = data.groupby('Balloons')['Count'].apply(lambda x: x/ x.sum()). But getting 1.00 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

```
data['Percentage'] = (data['Count']/data['Count'].sum()) *100
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
red_percent = 100 * red / (red + blue)
blue_percent = 100 * blue / (red + blue)
```

or:

```
red_percent = 100 * red / (red + blue)
blue_percent = 100 - red_percent
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I would need to store value in row i.e. data['percentages'] and then to have percentage for both red and blue in rows

Comment: do you need to generate another string from the string?

Comment: I tried data['Percentage'] = data.groupby('Balloons')['Count'].apply(lambda x: x/ x.sum()). But getting  1.00 for both red and blue :D